# toggleClass makes keeps both classes

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net

basically my question is pretty simple, 
I have two classes, my class widget and widget.active. 
Widget.active expands the width, so that its visible.

My jquery looks like this

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.widget').click(function () {
            $('.widget').toggleClass('widget.active');
        });
    });
```

When i click my "widget" it toggles, but it looks like this:

```
class="widget widget.active"
```

and it should only be widget.active.

Comment: you can't even style class `widget.active` in `css`, as your selector `.widget.active` will look for elements with both classes. That is invalid class name

Comment: @itsgoingdown: You *can* (`.widget\.active { /* ... */ }`), but it's not a good idea. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`class` is a **space**-delimited list, you don't put `.` in it.

If you have `class="widget"` and you want to go back and forth between `class="widget"` and `class="widget active"`, you want to toggle just `"active"`:

```
$('.widget').toggleClass('active');
```

That said, looking at the bigger picture, if your goal is to make the clicked widget active and to make any other widget non-active, `toggleClass` won't do it. You'd want:

```
$('.widget').not(this).removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");
```

...in your click handler:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.widget').click(function() {
    $('.widget').not(this).removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="widget active">Widget 1</div>
<div class="widget">Widget 2</div>
<div class="widget">Widget 3</div>
<div class="widget">Widget 4</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If your goal is to *individually* toggle widgets, just `$(this).toggleClass("active")`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.widget').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="widget active">Widget 1</div>
<div class="widget">Widget 2</div>
<div class="widget">Widget 3</div>
<div class="widget">Widget 4</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```